# Nginx doesn't pass Request-URI: field to SQUID

Tags: nginx, proxy, squid

I need to forward all requests to *80 port to nginx and then to Squid, But nginx forward request without Request-URI: /, here my nginx configuration

```
location / {

        proxy_pass http://proxy.testbet.lab;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host  $host;
        proxy_set_header Request-URI $request_uri;
}
```

on Squid access logs I see such log

```
1382365593.030      0 172.16.10.14 NONE/400 3542 GET / - NONE/- text/html
1382365593.034      0 172.16.10.14 NONE/400 3570 GET /Artwork/SN.png - NONE/- text/html
```

Comment: Have you checked whether nginx really isn't sending the header, or if squid is just ignoring it?  I was trying something similar and I could see in the nginx logs (if I turn up the log level in nginx) that it was sending a Request-URI header but squid wasn't paying any attention to it.